# OpenCV data types errors

Tags: c++, opencv

I am writing an application in C++ using OpenCV library. I am trying to do simple operations with matrices and on some data types operations output errors.

For example:

```
reduce(img, img, 0, CV_REDUCE_SUM, CV_8U); //does not work if img contains CV_8U
reduce(img, img, 0, CV_REDUCE_SUM, CV_64F); //does work if img contains CV_8U
```

And if try simple per element division:

```
Mat A = B / C; //generates data type assertion error if B and C are CV_32F
```

But does work if B and C are CV_64F.

I would really appreciate your help. Don't want to use CV_64F as it slows down my program significantly.

Comment: I've posted an answer for reduction operations. Division works perfectly with CV_32F types. Please provide a [mcve] to see where is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Reduction operations needs a suitable destination type, otherwise they will fail in case they might produce inconsistent result due to saturation.

If you are summing (`CV_REDUCE_SUM`) `CV_8U` values, you need a destination type big enough to contain the sum, which is either: `CV_32S`, `CV_32F` or `CV_64F`.

You can check this, as well as other combinations in the [source code](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp#L3739).